# Código para mostrar resolução da tela

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estou testando o site que estou criando em diversos dispositivos pra ver a responsividade, pois tenho 5 css uma para cada resolução de tela e **gostaria de criar um código dentro de uma div que mostrasse a resolução do dispositivo.** As informações que os fabricantes passam dos dispositivos, parece não ser o que é na realidade.
Quando meu site carregasse no meu dispositivo, essa div com o código me informaria a resolução da tela, para que eu possa ver onde devo mudar pois, utilizo vários css, dependendo da resolução. Sei que isso é possível via js, só não sei como fazer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você consegue pegar a resolução da tela com `window.innerWidth`, e jogar esse valor dentro da `div` com:

```
document.querySelector("#resolucao").innerHTML = window.innerWidth;
```

```js
document.querySelector("#resolucao").innerHTML = window.innerWidth;
```

```html
<div id="resolucao"></div>
```

Comment: é isso mesmo que eu queria. Muito obrigado!

Comment: Os atributos `window.innerWidth` e `javascript window.innerHeight` mostram o tamanho interno da janela do browser. Se alterar o tamanho da janela, estes valores mudam, ou seja, no desktop não irá funcionar. Veja se `screen.width` e `screen.height` não fica melhor pra você

Comment: @Dudaskank Exatamente, mas como ele está trabalhando com resoluções da janela para aplicar no comportamento dos elementos, o que importa nesse caso, é a resolução da janela, e não do ecrã todo. É que ele usou o termo errado :)

Answer (score 2):

### Objeto `screen`

Acredito que você está procurando pelo objeto `screen` no javascript. Ele te dá a resolução da tela onde a janela está.

```
// escrevendo a resulução no console
console.log('Total width/height: ' + screen.width + 'x' + screen.height);
// escrevendo dentro de um div
document.getElementById('idDoDivQueMostraResolucao').innerHTML = 'Total width/height: ' + screen.width + 'x' + screen.height;
```

### Media Query

Porém, você não precisa usar isso, pode colocar o chamado `media query` no próprio CSS. Esta abordagem também tem a vantagem de funcionar quando o usuário estiver com o javascript desabilitado. Assim não vai precisar também de um arquivo CSS para cada resolução.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
  body {
    background-color: lightgreen;
  }
}
```

### Imagens responsivas

Para o caso das imagens, ainda há outros modos, introduzidos no HTML5, que dispensam o uso de CSS ou de Javascript, deixando tudo por conta do browser.

### `srcset` e `sizes`

Os novos atributos da tag `img`, `srcset`  e `sizes`, são usados pelo navegador para selecionar a melhor imagem dependendo da resolução. No exemplo abaixo, o browser baixa apenas a imagem que melhor se adapta a um determinado cenário:

```
<img srcset="elva-fairy-320w.jpg 320w,
             elva-fairy-480w.jpg 480w,
             elva-fairy-800w.jpg 800w"
     sizes="(max-width: 320px) 280px,
            (max-width: 480px) 440px,
           800px"
     src="elva-fairy-800w.jpg" alt="Elva dressed as a fairy">
```

Com esses atributos no lugar, o navegador irá:

- Observar a largura do seu dispositivo (tela).
- Encontrar qual condição de mídia na lista de tamanhos (`atributo sizes`) é a primeira a ser verdadeira.
- Observar o tamanho do slot fornecido com essa consulta de mídia.
- Carrega a imagem referenciada na lista srcset que melhor corresponde ao tamanho escolhido.

### `picture`

Esta tag é Usada, por exemplo, nos casos em que uma imagem fica boa vendo no desktop em modo paisagem, mas num celular em modo retrato não fica legal. Aqui você cria uma outra imagem para o modo retrato que fique melhor.

```
<picture>
  <source media="(max-width: 799px)" srcset="elva-480w-close-portrait.jpg">
  <source media="(min-width: 800px)" srcset="elva-800w.jpg">
  <img src="elva-800w.jpg" alt="Chris standing up holding his daughter Elva">
</picture>
```

Nos browsers mais antigos, os atributos e tags novas são apenas ignorados.

### Mais informações

- https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_screen_width.asp
- https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp
- https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images
- https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ux/responsive/images

Comment: Como meu site é grande e tem muitas imagens achei melhor criar um css pra cada resolução em vez de ficar adicionando media querie pra cada item que quero mudar. Quanto as media querie e os css estou tranquilo, esta tudo certo aqui. O que eu preciso é de um js que mostra a resolução do dispositivo que estou acessando meu site, eu já tenho um arquivo criado `function.js` com todas as js do site, não entendi como eu adiciono o console.log que vc colocou, quero que apareça a resolução dentro da div que criei com nome `#resolucao`

Comment: `Como meu site é grande e tem muitas imagens achei melhor criar um css pra cada resolução em vez de ficar adicionando media querie pra cada item que quero mudar`. Com o tempo você verá que era menos esforço usar *media queries*.

Comment: Esse `console.log()` escreve no console javascript do browser, você acessa ele apertando F12 e clicando na aba console. Vou dar uma ajustada pra você ver como ficaria colocando em uma div. Sobre as várias imagens, aí você pode usar até outros meios, que também vou adicionar na resposta... aguarde um instante aí.

Comment: O que eu quero não é isso, quero esse js pra qdo acessar pelo celular, tablet, notbook eu saber qual a resolução do aparelho que estou acessando, entendeu? Quero que informe qual a resolução do dispositivo que estou acessando o site. Quero um codigo que me retorne a resolução do dispositivo. Eu acho que seja possível, só não faço idéia de como fazer!

Comment: Nosso amigo @ÐvÐ matou a questão, era isso que eu queria, obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Obrigado pelas informações, vou estudar elas pra me aprimorar, obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Acho que me empolguei um pouco rs... mas veja o comentário na resposta aceita, no notebook ou desktop aquele modo não é muito confiável.

Answer (score 0):

### Com jquery

> Com essa solução além de pegar a largura do dispositivo vai carregar o CSS adequado

**Biblioteca**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Script**

```
function adjustStyle(width) {

  //largura do dispositivo
  width = parseInt(width);
  //imprime a largura na div de id sizeWidth
  $( "#sizeWidth" ).text(width);

  //apenas um exemplo
  if (width < 701) {
    $("#size-stylesheet").attr("href", "style700.css");
  } else if (width < 900) {
    $("#size-stylesheet").attr("href", "style900.css");
  } else {
     $("#size-stylesheet").attr("href", "styleMaior900.css"); 
  }
}

$(function() {
  adjustStyle($(this).width());
  $(window).resize(function() {
    adjustStyle($(this).width());
  });
});
```

HTML

```
<link id="size-stylesheet" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="" />
<div id="sizeWidth"></div>
```

Comment: Faço isso com css `<!--Estilização para displays com até 768px-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/estilo-768.css" media="all and (min-width:481px) and (max-width:768px)">`. Acho mais fácil pois não manjo muito de js, qual a diferença de como eu uso pra esse?

Comment: Então, vc diz que `tenho 5 css uma para cada resolução de tela ` dai vc no if else determina para qual largura de tela vai imprimir no href da tag `<link id="size-stylesheet" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="" />`o css correspondente

Comment: @Clayton Furlanetto, seu modo não depende de javascript nem jquery, caso o usuário tenha desabilitado o javascript o seu continua funcionando. Também é menos código pra dar manutenção depois.

Comment: Pensando dessa forma, ele pode ter também  folha de estilo do usuário (prioridade mais elevada). Os usuários avançados de computador podem exibir páginas da Web usando seu próprio estilo customizado de folhas, dai baubau